# Qual è il significato di "ressa" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia del nuovo cognome* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Napoli mi era servita molto a Pisa, ma Pisa non serviva a Napoli, era un intralcio. Le buone maniere, la voce e l’aspetto curati, la **ressa** nella testa e sulla lingua di ciò che avevo imparato sui libri, erano tutti segnali immediati di debolezza che mi rendevano una preda sicura, di quelle che non si divincolano.

Ho cercato il significato di "ressa" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il senso di questo vocabolo nel brano precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

È il significato 2 nella voce del dizionario Treccani:

> Affollamento di gente che preme, che si accalca per entrare, per avvicinarsi, ecc.; la massa stessa di persone che così si affolla

Naturalmente è figurato: ciò che l'io narrante ha imparato si affolla nella testa e sulla lingua.

Con [questa ricerca in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=ressa%20in%20testa#tbm=bks&q=%22ressa%20nella%20testa%22) trovi altri esempi.

Answer (score 0):

In questo caso "ressa" è utilizzato in modo figurato e indica confusione